Error: Unexpected token 'N', "NodeAPIQue"... is not valid JSON
√ Enter a name for the new migration: ... addgraustemp
Applying migration `20240402142124_addgraustemp`

The following migration(s) have been created and applied from new schema changes:

migrations/
  └─ 20240402142124_addgraustemp/
    └─ migration.sql

Your database is now in sync with your schema.

Running generate... (Use --skip-generate to skip the generators)
Error: Unexpected token 'N', "NodeAPIQue"... is not valid JSON

After running "prisma migrate dev", show this error. I didn't find anything on the internet about it, can anyone help me?

What does your schema look like? What changes did you make to it? What does the generated migration look like?

I just include this model:
model Logs {
id               String   @id @default(cuid())
horarioTratador  DateTime
horarioAerador   DateTime
grausTemp        Decimal
horarioTemperatura DateTime @default(now())
}

Try using the same version in prisma and @prisma/client npm packages.
e.g. both should be "^5.18.0"
